# How to hide jLabel based on JOptionpane input

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

Basically, I click a JButton (unipedal) and it pops up with a JOptionPane with a few JTextFields. I want to take the String inputs of these JTextFields and:

1. Check to make sure the string values are in a HashMap I have of type  (posTasks.taskType), which they should be
2. Then create a new UNIPEDALImpl object with those Strings as parameters
3. Use the Strings as keys to another HashMap of type  (jLabelsHM) to hide the JLabel if the key of this HashMap returns true when used as a key in posTasks.completedTasks.

I am getting several errors and I can't figure out why.

```
unipedal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String robotName = null;
        String firstTask = null;
        String secondTask = null;
        String thirdTask = null;
        String fourthTask = null;
        String fifthTask = null;

        JPanel inputBox = new JPanel();
        inputBox.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 3, 4));

        JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField task1 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField task2 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField task3 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField task4 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField task5 = new JTextField(15);

        inputBox.add(new JLabel("Robot's Name:"));
        inputBox.add(name);

        inputBox.add(new JLabel("Task 1:"));
        inputBox.add(task1);

        inputBox.add(new JLabel("Task 2:"));
        inputBox.add(task2);

        inputBox.add(new JLabel("Task 3:"));
        inputBox.add(task3);

        inputBox.add(new JLabel("Task 4:"));
        inputBox.add(task4);

        inputBox.add(new JLabel("Task 5:"));
        inputBox.add(task5);

        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(middle,inputBox, 
       "Please fill all the fields", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

             robotName.equals(name.getText());
             firstTask.equals(task1.getText());
             secondTask.equals(task2.getText());
             thirdTask.equals(task3.getText());
             fourthTask.equals(task4.getText());
             fifthTask.equals(task5.getText());


            if (!posTasks.taskType.containsKey(firstTask)||!posTasks.taskType.containsKey(secondTask)||!posTasks.taskType.containsKey(thirdTask)||!posTasks.taskType.containsKey(fourthTask)||!posTasks.taskType.containsKey(fifthTask)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("One or more of the tasks you have requested are invalid. Please choose tasks from the list provided and check your spelling!");
            }
            try {
                UNIPEDALImpl unipedal = new UNIPEDALImpl(firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask, fourthTask,
                        fifthTask);

                LinkedList<String>tasksList = new LinkedList <String>();
                tasksList.add(firstTask);
                tasksList.add(secondTask);
                tasksList.add(thirdTask);
                tasksList.add(fourthTask);
                tasksList.add(fifthTask);

                for (String task : tasksList) {

                    if (posTasks.completedTasks.get(task) == true) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(task + "has already been completed. Please choose a different task or use 'refresh' if you want the task to be completed again");
                    }

                    unipedal.time += unipedal.taskTimes.get(task);
                    posTasks.completedTasks.put(task, true);
                    unipedal.tasksList.remove(task);
                    unipedal.taskCounter++;
                }

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (Entry<String, JLabel> entry : jLabelsHM.entrySet()) {
                if(posTasks.completedTasks.get(entry.getKey()) == true) {
                    jLabelsHM.get(entry.getKey()).setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `Check to make sure the string values are in a HashMap` - then why don't you use a JComboBox to display the list of valid Strings?

Comment: `"I am getting several errors and I can't figure out why."` -- wouldn't showing us those error messages be important and useful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Get rid of `@SuppressWarnings("null")`, and walk through your code to see why those null Strings are mines embedded within your code that will explode with a NullPointerException as you are using them.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 1):

First of all we don't have UNIPEDALImpl class here, so with a black-box view, I can not tell you if there is an error within that part.

About the problems in your code. first it seems that you want to fill your variable with equals method which is wrong, you need to use **= sign**.

***equals methos is for comparing two objects not assigning variables.***

```
robotName = name.getText();
firstTask = task1.getText();
secondTask = task2.getText();
thirdTask = task3.getText();
fourthTask = task4.getText();
fifthTask = task5.getText();
```

then you move from there.

Comment: Okay thanks. I tried this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is my RobotImpl class which is extended by UnipedalImpl: